# Another limit related to pi number

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find the value of the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{k!}^{2} {2}^{k}}{(2k+1)!}$$

I'm trying to find out if this limit can be computed only by using high school 
knowledge for solving limits. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mimicking [robjohn's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128680/) to the series, and after proving convergence, we may proceed as follows:

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{k!^2{2^k}}}{{\left( {2k + 1} \right)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {k - 1} \right)!^2{2^{k - 1}}}}{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( k \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {2k} \right)}}{2^{k - 1}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\operatorname{B} \left( {k,k} \right){2^{k - 1}}} $$

$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\operatorname{B} \left( {k,k} \right){2^{k - 1}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\int\limits_0^1 {{{\left[ {2t\left( {1 - t} \right)} \right]}^{k - 1}}dt} }  = \int\limits_0^1 {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{{\left[ {2t\left( {1 - t} \right)} \right]}^{k - 1}}} dt} $$

Then

$$=\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{dt}}{{1 - 2t\left( {1 - t} \right)}}}  = \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{dt}}{{1 - 2t + 2{t^2}}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{dt}}{{{{\left( {t - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}^2} + \frac{1}{4}}}} $$

Now let $t-1/2=u$.

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{ - 1/2}^{1/2} {\frac{{du}}{{{u^2} + {{\left( {1/2} \right)}^2}}}}  = \arctan 2\frac{1}{2} - \arctan 2\left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)$$

$$=2\arctan 1=2\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Does this qualify as "only...using high school knowledge"?

Comment: I had read the question a long time ago. I really forgot about that. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll try to find a solution using highschool knowledge, but it'd be good if the OP explicitly gives a repertoire. Some people learn definite integrals at highschool. The geometric series is easily taughtable, and the Beta integral might be a harder thing to get through.

Answer (score 3):

This is a formula of Euler (1737) giving **$\frac {\pi}2$**. A solution and a proof using the expansion of arctan may be found in Boris Gourévitch's ['World of pi'](http://www.pi314.net/eng/euler.php).
The following [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99809/how-to-prove-by-arithmetical-means-that-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack-1/99941#99941) could help too

Comment: indeed, the 2 links are helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris: you are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

If students don't know about the Gauss error function -- which is defined in terms of a non-elementary integral -- then *no*! Because the exact value of this infinite sum is $$\sqrt\frac{e \pi}2  \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)$$.

Comment: i think that the limit is $\frac {\pi}2$.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff: is that result equal to $\frac {\pi}2$?

Comment: No clue, I haven't checked it. I merely edited.

Comment: @ Peter Tamaroff: i thought you edited the result because you knew the answer. I know what is its limit and that's why i was asking for. As regards the limit, it is definitely  $\frac {\pi}2$.

Comment: @Chris I just TeXified it. I know the limit is $\pi /2$ but maybe murray can explain himself.

Comment: murray, the sum in question was $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{{k!}^{2} {2}^{k}}{(2k+1)!} = \frac{\pi}{2},$$ not $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k! {2}^{k}}{(2k+1)!} = \sqrt\frac{e \pi}2  \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right).$$  Note the square in the numerators of the summands.

Comment: Sorry, missed that square on the $k!$.

Comment: According to Mathematica, the tail-end of the infinite series -- after the terms through $k = n$, sums to a rational function of factorials and the hypergeometric $_2F_1(1, n + 2, n + 5/2; 1/2)$. So my answer to the original question would still be no -- at least assuming there's no simplification that avoids the hypergeometric function or some combination of gamma function expressions.