# Some infinite series with Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fibonacci-numbers

An interesting problem is to prove that:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{F_{2n}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{4\pi^2}{25 \sqrt 5}.
$$

I know the proof, which uses the fact that $\dfrac{1}{n\binom{2n}{n}}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}t^n(1-t)^{n-1}dt$, but my question is: *is there some really elementary way to prove it*?

Comment: Are you going to post your own answer to this?

Comment: If it is easy, why do you have to ask it here? This site is not meant for giving excersises to others, but this site is meant to ask for help if you are stuck. However, you can ask a question and self-answer it, that is, in fact, encouraged.

Comment: Not meant? Maybe it should.

Comment: @wythagoras you should have stated that as an opinion, as that's clearly not the point. Op clearly get's the underlying reason many people answer "questions" here. Besides, seeing something done a different way can be educational in its own right.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383068/finding-the-expansion-of-arcsinz2), and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99809/how-to-prove-by-arithmetical-means-that-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack-1) should be helpful.

Comment: MSE is not designed as a homework-solving platform or a training platform: the OP should be aware of that, but the problem in itself is really interesting, so I am quite against closing votes. It is related with the famous problem of finding the Taylor series of $\arcsin(z)^2$, with some special values for the dilogarithm and with the Euler acceleration technique. Please leave it here.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: so what is the problem/question and what is the point of leaving it on MSE?

Comment: @RobArthan: I think this question will be mentioned in a future blogpost of mine about that topic (dilogarithms, Euler acceleration method, squared arcsine, Catalan identity and so on).

Comment: A more cunning question is: why to remove it from where it is? The question, together with its answers, may turn useful/insightful for other users, now or in the future.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: the possibility of a reference in your blog isn't a good reason for keeping this post on MSE unless it's turned into a proper question. Please conspire with the OP to frame it as an interesting *question* if you want to keep it here.

Comment: @RobArthan: I do not agree with your opinion, but anyway I "started conspiring".

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: so providing raw material for your blog is a goal of MSE?

Comment: @RobArthan: not my blog, the MSE blog - http://math.blogoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** In general, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\displaystyle{2n\choose n}}~=~2\arcsin^2x.~$ Use this in conjunction with [Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) for [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio).

Comment: And with the fact that $\sin\frac{\pi}{10}=\frac{1}{2\varphi}$,$\sin\frac{3\pi}{10}=\frac{\varphi}{2}$, yes.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(n-1)!^2}{(2n)!} x^n = \sum_{n\geq 1}B(n,n)\frac{x^n}{2n}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}y^{n-1}(1-y)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{2n}\\&=&-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-xy+xy^2)}{y(1-y)}\,dy\end{eqnarray*} $$
hence by taking $\sigma_+=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\sigma_-=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{F_{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}&=&-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-\sigma_{+}(y-y^2))-\log(1-\sigma_{-}(y-y^2))}{y(1-y)}\,dy\\&=&-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-\sigma_+(1-u^2)/4)-\log(1-\sigma_-(1-u^2)/4)}{1-u^2}\,du\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the last integral can be computed by exploiting the [well-known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) relations between the dilogarithm and the golden ratio. Another technique is shown in [one of the answers I am most proud of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878477/a-closed-form-of-sum-k-0-infty-frac-1k1k-gamma2-left-frack2), a cooperative work by me, achille hui and Bhenni Benghorbal. It gives that the problem boils down to computing a squared arcsine.

Comment: Yes, right. Sorry, I really thought that there might be another way to prove it. Popped up in my mind after reading this interesting article http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf

Comment: @DanilKrotkov: that article is great. I don't if there is a really elementary way to prove your claim. Usually one computes special values for the dilogarithm by playing with the Euler-Landen identites and the reflection formulas.

Comment: @DanilKrotkov: anyway, have a look at my updated answer.