# Series with a reciprocal of the central binomial coefficient

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, polylogarithm

How can we prove the following identities
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-3}{\binom{2n}n}^{-1}=\pi\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)-\frac{4}{3}\zeta(3)\tag{1}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)^{-2}{\binom{2n}n}^{-1}=\frac{2\pi^2}{9}-2\pi\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)+\frac{8}{3}\zeta(3)-1\tag{2}$$
where $\operatorname{Cl}_2(x)$ is the [Clausen integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausensIntegral.html)?

Some identities of this sort are proved in [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf).

Comment: u could try to use the integral representation of the inverse binomials 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151441/calculate-sums-of-inverses-of-binomial-coefficients
and exchange integration and summation

Comment: See also: http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/cbc.pdf

Comment: Also [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$(1)$: We want to evaluate $\quad\displaystyle S:=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^3\binom{2m}{m}}$

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99941/21783) we obtained :
$$\tag{1}2(\arcsin(x))^2=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{2m}}{m^2\binom{2m}{m}}$$
Integrating this multiplied by $\,\dfrac 2x\,$ from $\,0$ to $\dfrac 12$ will thus give :
\begin{align}
S&=2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^2\binom{2m}{m}}\int_0^{\frac12}\dfrac{(2x)^{2m}}{x}\,dx\\
\tag{2}S&=4\int_0^{\frac 12} \frac{(\arcsin(x))^2}x\,dx\\
\tag{3}S&=4\int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{t^2}{\tan(t)}\,dt\\
S&=4\left[\left.t^2\log(\sin(t))\right|_{\,0}^{\,\pi/6}-2\int_0^{\pi/6} t\,\log(\sin(t))\,dt\right]\\
\tag{4}S&=-\frac{\log(2)\pi^2}9-8\int_0^{\pi/6} t\,\log(\sin(t))\,dt\\
\end{align}
The [Clausen integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClausenFunction.html) verifies :
$\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Cl}_2(x)'=-\log(2\sin(t/2))\;$ so let's rewrite $(4)$ and use integration by parts of $\operatorname{Cl}_2(x)$ :
\begin{align}
S&=-\frac{\log(2)\pi^2}9-\frac 84\int_0^{\pi/3} t\;\log(2\sin(t/2))-t\log(2)\,dt\\
\tag{5}S&=-2\int_0^{\pi/3} t\;\log(2\sin(t/2))\,dt\\
&=2\left[t\;\operatorname{Cl}_2(x)\left.\right|_0^{\pi/3}-\int_0^{\pi/3} \operatorname{Cl}_2(t)\,dt\right]\\
&=\frac{2\pi}3\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{\pi}3\right)+2\,\left(\operatorname{Cl}_3\left(\frac{\pi}3\right)-\operatorname{Cl}_3\left(0\right)\right)\\
\end{align}
Since $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Cl}_{2n}(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(k\,x)}{k^{\,2n}},\ \operatorname{Cl}_{2n+1}(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(k\,x)}{k^{\,2n+1}}\;$ [we have indeed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Derivatives_of_general_order_Clausen_functions) $\;\operatorname{Cl}_3(x)'=-\operatorname{Cl}_2(x)$.

Now $\,\operatorname{Cl}_3(0)=\zeta(3)\,$ and $\,\operatorname{Cl}_3\left(\dfrac{\pi}3\right)=\dfrac{\zeta(3)}3\,$ (prove this using the series for $\operatorname{Cl}_3$) while $\,\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)=\dfrac 23\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\dfrac{\pi}3\right)\,$ can't be written in simpler form (without using polylogarithms) so that your $(1)$ is indeed right :
$$\boxed{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^{3}{\binom{2n}n}}=\pi\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-\frac{4}{3}\zeta(3)}\tag{6}$$

---

$(2)$: Concerning $\;\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}}\ $ the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99941/21783) (i.e. the derivative of $(1)$ multiplied by $\dfrac x2$) gives us :
$$\tag{7}\frac{2x \arcsin\ x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{2m}}{m\binom{2m}{m}}$$
The derivative of this (multiplied by $x/2$) will give us the general  :

$$\tag{8}\boxed{\frac {x^2}{1-x^2}+x\frac {\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}^3}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{2m}}{\binom{2m}{m}}}$$

Multiplying by $\,x$, integrating and dividing by $x^2/2$ we get :

$$\tag{9}2\frac {\arcsin(x)}{x\,\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{\arcsin(x)^2}{x^2}-1=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{2m}}{(m+1)\binom{2m}{m}}$$

The indefinite integral of $\;\displaystyle 2\;x\frac {\arcsin(x)}{x\,\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;$ is simply $\,\arcsin(x)^2\,$ while the integral of $\;\displaystyle x\frac{\arcsin(x)^2}{x^2}$ is more complicated *but* we found $\;\displaystyle\int_0^{1/2}\frac {\arcsin(x)^2}x\,dx=\frac S4$ earlier and can therefore conclude that :
$$\int_0^{1/2} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{x(2x)^{2m}}{(m+1)\binom{2m}{m}}\,dx=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-3}(1)^{2m+2}}{(m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}}=\left.\arcsin(x)^2-\frac{x^2}2\right|_{\,0}^{\,1/2}-\frac S4$$
or :
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{(m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}}=8\left(\frac{\pi}6\right)^2-\frac 88-2\left(\pi\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-\frac{4}{3}\zeta(3)\right)$$
which is indeed your equality $(2)$ :
$$\tag{10}\boxed{\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{(m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}}=\frac{2\pi^2}{9}-2\pi\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)+\frac{8}{3}\zeta(3)-1}$$

To add to the links provided by Vladimir Reshetnikov :

- an excellent link concerning central binomial series is to [Gourévitch's $\pi$ pages](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse11.php).
- here [Sprugnoli's "Sums of reciprocals of the central binomial coefficients"](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf) may be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks @tired! (the simplification in $(4)$ and $(3)$ or $(2)$ could possibly provide a more direct derivation... not sure). Cheers,

Comment: This is real nice ! Perfect illustration of the fact that *beauty* and *mathematics* go together. Cheers.

Comment: Glad you liked that @Claude! I am fond (as you know) of zeta, polygamma, polylogarithms, Clausen functions and all that stuff that marry very well with generating functions. Cheers,