# Show that, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{{n^2}{2n\choose n}}=\ln^2(2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The central binomial $${2n\choose n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

The series for natural logarithmic of $\ln(2)$ is

$$\ln(2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$$

and the integral for it is $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx=\ln(2)$$

Show that,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{{n^2}{2n\choose n}}=\ln^2(2)$$

**Can anybody help me to prove this sum, I found it through mathematical experimental.**

I guess if there is an integral for, $\frac{1}{n^2{2n\choose n}}=\int_0^1f(x,n)dx$ it might be helpful.

I know that $\frac{2^n}{(2n+1){2n\choose n}}=\int_0^1[2x(1-x)]^ndx$

Comment: A [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383068/finding-the-expansion-of-arcsinz2) for some inspiration (you are encouraged too to provide answers). Excellent continuation (with pure imaginary!),

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99809/how-to-prove-by-arithmetical-means-that-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack-1/128680#128680

Comment: @MarcoCantarini (+1), I read it still not sure how to use it to solve this problem, any more help

Comment: @pisquare In the links posted by me and Raymond Manzoni there are proofs of the identity $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{k^{2}\binom{2k}{k}}(2x)^{2k}=\arcsin^{2}(x).$ So you have only to take $x=\frac{i}{2\sqrt{2}}$ and use the definition $(1)$ of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html

Comment: @Marco Cantarini (+1), I see!

Comment: Can you explain what "I found it through mathematical experimental" really means?

Comment: Simple Mr jack. 2,4,6,8,...2n

Comment: Hi @JackD'Aurizio also this account too. I want to end this maths staff here, wasting a lot of my in writing and not doing my quest for finding new formulas.

Comment: I don't get it. How can you claim a specific value for a series by checking (what?) for $2,4,6,8,\ldots,2n$?

Comment: Mr Jack I am starting to see that you are nice man. I am apologising for insulting you. I can see your proved of my proposed questions is wonderful concise and full of detail. Explaining how i got these formulas from maths experimental and guessing is quite not easy to explain. I may find an example in the future and show it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Using these formulas:
 $$(\arcsin(x))^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}$$

$$\arcsin(x)=i\ln(ix+\sqrt{1-x^2})$$

$$-2\ln^2(ix+\sqrt{1-x^2})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}$$

Let $x=\frac{i}{2\sqrt2}$

Simplify it and you should get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{{n^2}{2n\choose n}}=\ln^2(2)$$